# How do I create a collection view inside of another collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a profile page on my app and I want to have a section like instagram has where you can scroll horizontally from on to the other.

I want to have 3 sections that looks like this:

[image]

where a user can scroll left and right to on of the tabs either pictures videos or posts.

I have tries to use a collection view with three cells one for each tab and then add another collection view inside of each cell to hold all the images and videos and posts for the respective tab but i can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work or even if this is possible.

When I create a collection view with one cell and load all the pictures in it it works but then i don't know how I would get the other two tabs to work.

This is how I have got a different cell for each tab:

```
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UserPostCell
    } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: videoCell, for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
    } else {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: messageCell, for: indexPath) as! PostMessageCell
    }
```

I cant seem to figure out how to go from here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That looks more like a custom `UISegmentedControl` to be honest

Comment: i will try that thank you

Answer (score 0):

what I understand is you have a nested collection view and you want to reload it on different screens with different data. here is the solution
declare a variable first

```
var loadCollectionViewFor: String?
```

then on picture, video, and story
assign var a value like on pictures it goes like

```
loadCollectionViewFor = "picture"
collectionView.reloadData()
```

then in numberOfItemsInSection

```
if collectionView == usersCollectionView{
            if loadCollectionViewFor == "picture" {
                
                return pictures.count
                
            } else{
                return vedio.count ?? 0
                
            }
        }
```

and use the same for cellForItemAt Thanks